# How do I create this layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-tablelayout

How do I create this layout in android

```
---------------------
|col1 | col2 | col3 |
|  col1   |  col2   |
---------------------
```

The first row is 3 columns equal width, and the second row is 2 row equal width.
Is it possible to create this in TableLayout ? 
I did try width android:layout_span="2" for the last cell, but it does not end up in equal width.

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TableRow android:layout_marginTop="6dp">
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_weight="33"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/percent" />
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_weight="33"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/percent" />
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_weight="33"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/percent" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:layout_marginTop="6dp">
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_weight="60"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/percent" />
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_weight="40"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/percent" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: have you tried using two TableLayouts? I mean change your root layout to RelativeLayout, then add two TableLayouts, one handles the 3 columns, the other one handles the 2 columns.

Comment: Tip: play with **weights** inside *LinearLayout* and its easy to achieve...

Comment: You used layout_weight 60 and 40 for the two components on the second table row. Use 50 and 50

Comment: @anonim you have to accept an answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use LinearLayout for getting that result, try with this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
       <Button 
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/percent" />
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/percent" />
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/percent" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

         <Button 
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/percent" />
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/percent" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the 2nd row, do not use span and put equal weight:

```
<TableRow android:layout_marginTop="6dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:text="@string/percent"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:text="@string/percent"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</TableRow>
```